# Google Play Billing 6.0.0 queryPurchasesAsync

Tags: java, android, android-studio, play-billing-library

When I used the below code I got **Server Disconnected** error message

```
mBillingClient.queryPurchasesAsync(QueryPurchasesParams.newBuilder().setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.INAPP).build(), new PurchasesResponseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onQueryPurchasesResponse(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult, @NonNull List<Purchase> list) {
                if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                    showToast("success");
                } else if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.SERVICE_DISCONNECTED) {
                    showToast("error");
                }
            }
        });
```

I'm using play billing library **6.0.0**. Help me to get non consumable purchase history

Comment: have you previously connected with `mBillingClient.startConnection(...)`?